# Why is "[ok]" not shown in daemon status message when using GNU Screen?

Tags: terminal, gnu-screen

I have a debian-based system (Voyage Linux 0.9.1 actually, which is based on debian wheezy) and when I do `/etc/init.d/ntp status` it returns (for example)

```
$ /etc/init.d/ntp status
[ ok ] NTP server is running
```

However, inside a screen session (version 4.01.00devel 2-May-06) the `[ ok ]` is not shown.

```
$ screen
$ /etc/init.d/ntp status
NTP server is running
```

**Why is this the case? And how to show it also in the Screen session?**

BTW: On another debian server (which also returns `xterm-256color` when I do `echo $TERM`), I noticed that `/etc/init.d/ntp status` does never show the `[ ok ]`, regardless of whether I am in a screen session or not, so it probably is not really a `screen` issue.

Answer (score 5):

It doensn't require screen. Let's experiment:

```
TERM=dumb /etc/init.d/ntp status  # no [OK]
/etc/init.d/ntp status | cat      # also no [OK]
```

This also leaves out the `[OK]`. Since abviously the output differs based on the TERM setting (`dumb` and `screen` drop the `[OK]`), you can pretend to have a fully featured terminal instead of screen:

```
TERM=xterm /etc/init.d/ntp status
```

And it seems to detect as well if it's connected to a terminal. When you pipe the output to another process, the `[OK]` vanishes.

I assume the reason for this is that due to the use of escape codes for the `[OK]`, there is a check which prevents their use in “unsave” environments. The escape sequences do not really add anything, but they might mess up the output.

The terminal capability check is done in `/lib/lsb/init-functions`. There's a function called `log_use_fancy_output` which makes use of [`tput`](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=tput&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian+unstable+sid&format=html&locale=en):

> `tput` The  tput utility uses the terminfo database to make the values of terminal-dependent capabilities and information  available  to  the  shell

It issues the following two commands:

```
tput hpa 60
tput setaf 1
```

From [tput: Portable Terminal Control](https://www.gnu.org/software/termutils/manual/termutils-2.0/html_chapter/tput_1.html) and [Bash Prompt HOWTO - Colours and Cursor Movement](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x405.html):

```
hpa          - Move cursor to column #1
setaf [1-7]  - Set a foreground colour using ANSI escape
```

In particular `log_use_fancy_output` checks if it is connected to a terminal. It then checks if TERM is empty or set to dumb and if those two `tput` operations succeed. If that  is successfull, the `[OK]` is printed, otherwise the `[OK]` is skipped.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, it seem that the outputting  of "[ ok ]" or "[FAIL]" in front of daemons is handled by `/lib/lsb/init-functions` which contains a function `log_use_fancy_output()` that indeed queries the capabilities of the terminal using `tput`. It check for something like `tput hpa 60` and `tput setaf 1` although it is unclear to me from the `tput` man page what that exactly means...